# How to cache a paginated Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, memcached, django-views

How do you cache a paginated Django queryset, specifically in a ListView?

I noticed one query was taking a long time to run, so I'm attempting to cache it. The queryset is huge (over 100k records), so I'm attempting to only cache paginated subsections of it. I can't cache the entire view or template because there are sections that are user/session specific and need to change constantly.

ListView has a couple standard methods for retrieving the queryset, `get_queryset()`, which returns the non-paginated data, and `paginate_queryset()`, which filters it by the current page.

I first tried caching the query in `get_queryset()`, but quickly realized calling `cache.set(my_query_key, super(MyView, self).get_queryset())` was causing the entire query to be serialized.

So then I tried overriding `paginate_queryset()` like:

```
import time
from functools import partial
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyView(ListView):

    ...

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        cache_key = 'myview-queryset-%s-%s' % (self.page, page_size)
        print 'paginate_queryset.cache_key:',cache_key
        t0 = time.time()
        ret = cache.get(cache_key)
        if ret is None:
            print 're-caching'
            ret = super(MyView, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
            cache.set(cache_key, ret, 60*60)
        td = time.time() - t0
        print 'paginate_queryset.time.seconds:',td
        (paginator, page, object_list, other_pages) = ret
        print 'total objects:',len(object_list)
        return ret
```

However, this takes almost a minute to run, even though only 10 objects are retrieved, and every requests shows "re-caching", implying nothing is being saved to cache.

My `settings.CACHE` looks like:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

and `service memcached status` shows memcached is running and `tail -f /var/log/memcached.log` shows absolutely nothing.

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to cache a paginated query so that the entire queryset isn't retrieved?

Edit: I think their may be a bug in either memcached or the Python wrapper. Django appears to support two different memcached backends, one using python-memcached and one using pylibmc. The python-memcached seems to silently hide the error caching the `paginate_queryset()` value. When I switched to the pylibmc backend, now I get an explicit error message "error 10 from memcached_set: SERVER ERROR" tracing back to django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py in set, line 78.

Comment: Does the low-level cache API work from django shell? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/#basic-usage

Comment: Yes, it seems to work for simple immutable objects and even basic querysets. It only seems to fail when caching the value returned by `paginate_queryset()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the `Paginator` to support caching by a provided `cache_key`.

A blog post about usage and implementation of a such `CachedPaginator` can be found [here](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/07/cachedpaginator/). The source code is posted at [djangosnippets.org](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1173/) (here is a [web-acrhive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927100427/https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1173/) because the original is not working).

However I will post a slightly modificated example from the original version, which can not only cache objects per page, but the total count too. (sometimes even the count can be an expensive operation).

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, Page, PageNotAnInteger


class CachedPaginator(Paginator):
    """A paginator that caches the results on a page by page basis."""
    def __init__(self, object_list, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True, cache_key=None, cache_timeout=300):
        super(CachedPaginator, self).__init__(object_list, per_page, orphans, allow_empty_first_page)
        self.cache_key = cache_key
        self.cache_timeout = cache_timeout

    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        """
            The original django.core.paginator.count attribute in Django1.8
            is not writable and cant be setted manually, but we would like
            to override it when loading data from cache. (instead of recalculating it).
            So we make it writable via @cached_property.
        """
        return super(CachedPaginator, self).count

    def set_count(self, count):
        """
            Override the paginator.count value (to prevent recalculation)
            and clear num_pages and page_range which values depend on it.
        """
        self.count = count
        # if somehow we have stored .num_pages or .page_range (which are cached properties)
        # this can lead to wrong page calculations (because they depend on paginator.count value)
        # so we clear their values to force recalculations on next calls
        try:
            del self.num_pages
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        try:
            del self.page_range
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    @cached_property
    def num_pages(self):
        """This is not writable in Django1.8. We want to make it writable"""
        return super(CachedPaginator, self).num_pages

    @cached_property
    def page_range(self):
        """This is not writable in Django1.8. We want to make it writable"""
        return super(CachedPaginator, self).page_range

    def page(self, number):
        """
        Returns a Page object for the given 1-based page number.

        This will attempt to pull the results out of the cache first, based on
        the requested page number. If not found in the cache,
        it will pull a fresh list and then cache that result + the total result count.
        """
        if self.cache_key is None:
            return super(CachedPaginator, self).page(number)

        # In order to prevent counting the queryset
        # we only validate that the provided number is integer
        # The rest of the validation will happen when we fetch fresh data.
        # so if the number is invalid, no cache will be setted
        # number = self.validate_number(number)
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise PageNotAnInteger('That page number is not an integer')

        page_cache_key = "%s:%s:%s" % (self.cache_key, self.per_page, number)
        page_data = cache.get(page_cache_key)

        if page_data is None:
            page = super(CachedPaginator, self).page(number)
            #cache not only the objects, but the total count too.
            page_data = (page.object_list, self.count)
            cache.set(page_cache_key, page_data, self.cache_timeout)
        else:
            cached_object_list, cached_total_count = page_data
            self.set_count(cached_total_count)
            page = Page(cached_object_list, number, self)

        return page
```

Comment: This is hugely useful -- I appreciate the care you went into around caching the count

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be a combination of factors. Mainly, the result returned by the `paginate_queryset()` contains a reference to the unlimited queryset, meaning it's essentially uncachable. When I called `cache.set(mykey, (paginator, page, object_list, other_pages))`, it was trying to serialize thousands of records instead of just the `page_size` number of records I was expecting, causing the cached item to exceed memcached's limits and fail.

The other factor was the horrible default error reporting in the memcached/python-memcached, which silently hides all errors and turns cache.set() into a nop if anything goes wrong, making it very time-consuming to track down the problem.

I fixed this by essentially rewriting `paginate_queryset()` to ditch Django's builtin paginator functionality altogether and calculate the queryset myself with:

```
object_list = queryset[page_size*(page-1):page_size*(page-1)+page_size]
```

and then caching **that** `object_list`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to paginate my infinite scrolling view on my home page and this is the solution I came up with. It's a mix of Django CCBVs and the author's initial solution.

The response times, however, didn't improve as much as I would've hoped for but that's probably because I am testing it on my local with just 6 posts and 2 users haha.

```
    # Import
    from django.core.cache import cache
    from django.core.paginator import InvalidPage
    from django.views.generic.list import ListView
    from django.http Http404

    class MyListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'MY TEMPLATE NAME'
    model = MY POST MODEL
    paginate_by = 10



    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):

        """Paginate the queryset"""
        paginator = self.get_paginator(
            queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
            allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())

        page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg

        page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1

        try:
            page_number = int(page)

        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages

            else:
                raise Http404(_("Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int."))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            cache_key = 'mylistview-%s-%s' % (page_number, page_size)
            retreive_cache = cache.get(cache_key)

            if retreive_cache is None:
                print('re-caching')
                retreive_cache = super(MyListView, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)

                # Caching for 1 day
                cache.set(cache_key, retreive_cache, 86400)

            return retreive_cache
        except InvalidPage as e:
            raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                'page_number': page_number,
                'message': str(e)
            })
```

Comment: is this question still relevant? could you not cache the url at the view level with the latest version of django (4.1)? 

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache. presumably the cache would treat each request with a different query param as a unique url and cache each url, right? or am i misunderstanding the django docs?

Comment: yes, i think it would cache each combination of a query param as a unique url. see this section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers where it says, "By default, Django’s cache system creates its cache keys using the requested fully-qualified URL – e.g., 'https://www.example.com/stories/2005/?order_by=author'."

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of how to use the wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057137/3139228) by Todor to cache pagination within `ListView`. It is assumed that you have several `ListView` in your app. Each of them requires its own distinct `cache_key`. You add `paginator_class = CachedPaginator` and overwrite the `get_paginator` function by parent class.

```
from myapp.utils import CachedPaginator

class ModelAView(ListView):
    model = ModelA
    template_name = "model_a.html"
    paginator_class = CachedPaginator  # instead of default Paginator
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_paginator(
        self, queryset, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True, **kwargs
    ):
        paginator_cache_key = "model_a_" + str(self.kwargs["model_a_pk"])
        return self.paginator_class(
            queryset,
            per_page,
            orphans=orphans,
            allow_empty_first_page=allow_empty_first_page,
            cache_key=paginator_cache_key,
            **kwargs,
        )
```