# Simple pagination of Django class-based listview failing, template caching to blame?

Tags: django, python-2.7, caching, pagination, django-templates

In a web-based social Django app I have, there's a feature that allows users to see all unique users who had a session in the past 5 mins. For this, I'm using [django user_sessions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions), a plugin that

> makes session objects a first class citizen like other ORM objects.

These recent users are displayed as a list on a template. Each name generated is clickable on this template - clicking it takes the clicker to the clickee's profile page. To accomplish that, I've simply wrapped each username in this tag: `<a href="{% url 'profile' slug=unique_session.user.username %}#section0"></a>`. This template is **cached**, via using the template tags: `{%load cache %}{%% cache 30 template_fragment_2 %}{% endcache %}`

Furthermore, the list of recent online users is paginated by 75 (accomplished via adding `paginate_by = 75` in the `listview` that generates the said list).

Here is the problem: the list of recent users loads up fine in the template (and clicked usernames lead to correct profiles), but once a user presses "next page" (*i.e. there were more than 75 people to show*), I get the error: **django.core.urlresolvers:NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': ''}' not found.** After a lot of debugging, I still have no idea why this is happening. Is it because of `cache` and `pagination`? Help!

---

The view that generates the list is as follows:

```
from user_sessions.models import Session

class OnlineView(ListView):
    model = Session
    template_name = "online.html"
    paginate_by = 75

    def get_queryset(self):
        unique_user_sessions = Session.objects.filter(last_activity__gte=(timezone.now()-timedelta(minutes=5))).only('user').distinct('user')
        return unique_user_sessions
```

And the code in the template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% load cache %}
    {% cache 30 template_fragment2 %}
    <div class="margin">
        <ol>
            {% for unique_session in object_list %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=unique_session.user.username %}#section0">
                        {% if unique_session.user.userprofile.avatar %}
                            <img src="{{ unique_session.user.userprofile.avatar.url }}" alt="no pic" height="20" width="20"></img>
                        {% else %}
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/default-avatar.jpg" alt="no pic" height="20" width="20"></img>
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ unique_session.user.username }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </div>
    {% endcache %}
{% endblock %}

{% block pagination %}
{% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}#section0">back</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}#section0">forward</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here are relevant urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$', UserProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile'),
url(r'^online/$', auth(OnlineView.as_view()), name='online'),
```

---

Lastly,

```
Stack trace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 174, in run
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 540, in spawn_workers
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 124, in init_process
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 119, in run
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 66, in run_for_one
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 30, in accept
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 704, in __iter__
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 1080, in __call__
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 83, in __call__
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 1208, in _nr_wsgi_application_wrapper_
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 98, in dynamic_wrapper
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 98, in dynamic_wrapper
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.56.0.42/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 702, in wrapper
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/cache.py", line 34, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 195, in render
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 424, in render
```

Comment: Can you post: your `urls.py`, the stack trace generated by the `NoReverseMatch` error, and your pagination template code?

Comment: @solarissmoke: pagination code added at the end of the template code, followed by 2 urlpatterns (do you need to see the whole thing?), and lastly, the stack trace generated. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination code itself is fine. I think the issue is that some of the `user` objects that is being returned on the second page of results have an empty `username`, which is what causes the `NoReverseMatch` error.

The most likely cause of this is that `user` object being returned is an [anonymous user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users) - the `username` is always an empty string in this case.

To verify try modifying your template by wrapping that block in this check:

```
{% if not unique_session.user.is_anonymous %}
    <li>
        <a>...
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'll try this. Meanwhile, I was doing my own digging into the issue. Here's something I found of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083746/how-to-cache-a-paginated-django-queryset

Comment: No is_anonymous didn't make a dent on the problem unfortunately, I get precisely the same error! (meaning it goes inside that if statement)

Comment: Though, when I catered to user being "None", it worked!